# Redirect Specific Subdomains URLs to Specific URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel, http-status-code-301

I am transferring my blog over from a subdomain to domain and was wondering how to write the very specific 301 redirects.

*blog.domain.com/blog-post* >> *domain.com/blog-post*

*blog.domain.com/blog-post-2* >> *domain.com/blog-post-2*

We are leaving our current content service (Hubspot) which required the subdomain. I have about 20 URLs to redirect.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect requests for `blog.domain.com/uri` to `domain.com/uri`